# Scrolling through colors effect in RGB

Tags: colors, rgb

I want to create a colour scroller effect. I have a function that I give it RGB values (eg. setColor(189,234,45)) and I want to change the colour rapidly but I don't want to get many repeats to create an effect of scrolling through the colours.

I have tried tried the following but it doesn't quite generate the effect that I am looking for.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++) {
        setColor(i, j, k);
      }
    }
  }
```

I wanted to know if anyone knows how the colour scroller's colours are arranged next to each other. The arrangement I am looking for looks like the [scroll on the right](http://vddotnet.erdalhalici.com/images/ColorPicker/ColorPickerUICMYKHSBColorSpace.PNG).

Comment: What is wrong with what this code gives you?

Comment: It is both a very long sequence and it repeats colours with very slight differences.

Comment: I forgot to say: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It would be "good practice" to edit your answer with the extra information you provided.    It's also good practice to upvote answers that help you, and accept one that solves the problem for you.  Cheers...

Comment: I'm too much of noob to be able to upvote (you need 15 rep to upvote) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your edit, you don't like the sequence of colours, because you start from black an end at white, instead of starting at one end of the rainbow and going to the other.

So you are going to need to work out a sequence of RGB that goes from blue through green and yellow to red. That means you need to start with (0,0,255) and end at (255, 0, 0), and don't pass through (255,255,255) or (0,0,0) - in a nutshell, that's how its done.

There are many ways you could do this and get a pleasing effect - beyond the scope of an answer here.   This article explores it in depth:

http://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php

Comment: The link is great especially the title "Making annoying rainbows in javascript". The guy really knows his colours.

Answer (score 3):

The colors you are working with are represented as R,G,B (red green blue) values.  However, another
way to think about color is hue, saturation, value.  In the scroll image you are trying to emulate,
it is the hue that is changing - the saturation and value (brightness) are unaffected.

Here is a function that happens to make a hue-cycle gradient like the one in the image you linked to:

```
int n = 256; // number of steps
float TWO_PI = 3.14159*2;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int red = 128 + sin(i*TWO_PI/n + 0) + 127;
    int grn = 128 + sin(i*TWO_PI/n + TWO_PI/3) + 127;
    int blu = 128 + sin(i*TWO_PI/n + 2*TWO_PI/3) + 127;
    setColor(red, grn, blu);
}
```

To understand how that function works, I recommend that you read my [color tutorial](http://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php) that GreenAsJade linked to.

However, that kind of gradient function isn't quite what you need, because you want to start from a particular color you are passing in, and then go to the next color in the sequence.  It's much easier to do this kind of thing if you represent your colors as HSV triplets (or HSB triplets), instead of RGB triplets.  Then you can manipulate just the hue component, and get those kind of rainbow effects.  In helps to have a set of function that can convert from RGB to HSV and back again.

[This site](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html) contains a bunch of color conversion source code, including the ones you need for those conversions.  Using the two conversion functions supplied on that page, your code might look like:

```
void cycleMyColor(int *r, int *g, int *b) {
    float h,s,v,  fr,fg,fb;
    RGBtoHSV(*r/255.0,*g/255.0,*b/255.0,&h,&s,&v);
    h += 1/256.0;  // increment the hue here
    h -= (int) h;  // and cycle around if necessary
    HSVtoRGB(&fr,&fg,&fb,h,s,v);
    *r = fr*255; *g = fg*255; *b = fb*255;
    setColor(*r,*g,*b);
}
```

This code is a little more complicated than it needs to be because the color conversions on that site use floating point color components that go from 0-1, instead of integers that go from 0-255, as you were using, so I'm spending a few lines converting between those two representations.  You may find it simpler to just keep your color in HSB space, and then convert to RGB when you want to display it.

Comment: Instead of 128 + (calculated value) + 127, why not just add 255? Looking at your blog page I see you meant to say (calculated value) * 127. Anyway, thank you for this. Though it seems to skip over yellow, it goes from green to orangey green to orange.